# How to find text in string and show only some text in php

Tags: php

Example

```
asdad=213131233&mkmaosikdmnoacmaskldmakl%asdasdad&asdad=81248&aklsdnadnasdnjasdnjkandjk
```

Result

```
213131233

81248
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), Working [solution](https://tehplayground.com/3dx6ZF8xX3i3t41e).

```
$str = "asdad=213131233&mkmaosikdmnoacmaskldmakl%asdasdad&asdad=81248&aklsdnadnasdnjasdnjkandjk
";
preg_match_all("~=(.*?)&~", $str, $out);
print_r($out[1]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 213131233
   [1] => 81248
)
```

Comment: much more easier way:- https://3v4l.org/9bDLJ .... (check duplicate thread)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie interesting solution, Thank you. I love it when someone shares a better/easier approach.